# How to validate input values when user clicks on action button in shiny

Tags: validation, shiny

I am developing a shiny dashboard where user can send emails when he clicks on `send email` button. When user clicks on send email button validation needs to be performed on various input fields. Here is my `ui.R` file look like

```
tabItem("email",
          fluidRow(
            box(
              width = 5, status = "info",solidHeader = TRUE,
              title = "Send Emails",
              helpText(tags$b("If no selection is made, emails will be sent to all the registrants with today's date")),

              dateRangeInput('dateRange',
                             label = 'Date Range Input',
                             start = c("",Sys.Date() - 2), end = c("",Sys.Date() + 2)

              ),
              selectizeInput("email_select", 
                             "Select Email Content",
                             choices = c("Price" = "price",
                                         "Services" = "service"
                                         ),
                             options = list(
                             placeholder = 'Please select',
                             onInitialize = I('function() { this.setValue(""); }')
                          )
                          ),
              uiOutput("city_dropdown")
         )
         )
```

`uiOutput` is a dropdown box which gets populated once data is uploaded. Here is my `server.R` file looking like

```
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

    output$city_dropdown <- renderUI({

       city <- reg_city(final_data)
       city <- city$registrant_city
       city <- as.list(city)

       selectizeInput("city_select", 
                      "Select City",
                      choices = city,
                      options = list(
                      placeholder = 'Please select',
                      onInitialize = I('function() { this.setValue("");}')
                     )

            )


   })

  observeEvent(input$send_email, {
     city <- input$city_select

     if(city == ""){
       validate(
       need(input$city_select != '', 'Please choose a city')

    )}
```

But when I click on action button nothing happens,it does not display error message if no city is selected from drop down box.
Please help.

Comment: see `?req`. Essentially in your `observeEvent` you tell it not to evaluate if certain things aren't true.

Comment: Could you please provide the code with reproducible error. It is very hard to figure out what is having with the code you have provided